# How to break or exit in Firebase object on child loop using jquery?

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to exit in a loop of object in Firebase after a certain condition. I tried using return false but it doesn't work. Can someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
function checkRoom(room_id,user_id,other_user){


    var  dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref('chat-list');
    //getting all keys 
    dbRefObject.on('child_added', function (snap) {
        if(snap.key == 1){
            //if condition succeed the loop will exit
            return false; //but return false is not working here.
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To break out of a snapshot's `forEach` iteration, you need to [return `true`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach).

The `forEach` method's `action` parameter is:

> A function that will be called for each child DataSnapshot. The callback can return `true` to cancel further enumeration.

Note that you can break out of the iteration by returning any truthy value - not just `true`.

Comment: No worries. Note that the fact that any truthy value will break out of the iteration can lead to fun behaviour if you use arrow functions. For example, `snapshot.forEach(item => items.push(item))` will break after the first push. You'd need to use `snapshot.forEach(item => { items.push(item); })`. Just something to be aware of.